# disabling revision feature from couchDB

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I'm using couch db to insert values in bulk, and to do a lot of reads based on a date stamp.

The revision id is not something I need IMO, because I'm not planning on doing any updates. Is it possible to disable this feature to save on some space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not disable revision id's. Even if you could I don't think there would be any significant gain in disk space. There are however other methods that can help you make a considerable difference:-

1. Keep the keys small: For example use `ver` instead of `version` in key.
2. Use you own _id fields which can help reduce disk size dramatically. Check [out the docs](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/maintenance/performance.html#document-s-id) for more info on this.
3. Compress from time to time. Maybe [configure couchdb](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/misc.html#attachments/compression_level) to use the highest compression level.

Comment: I did do #1, I'm more concerned about quick reads than space, so I'm hesitant on compressing. I will look into the ids though. Thanks